# Why picker view does not show data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7

I have a button that when when pressed shows a view. And inside the view, there are picker view and a toolbar.PickerView does not show data. I cannot find the reason why the data is not appearing. Can somebody help me?

my RealViewController.h

```
#define option1 2

@interface RealViewController : UIViewController
<NSURLConnectionDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *arrayOption;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerOutlet1;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOption;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewContainer;
-(IBAction)showViewContainer;
-(IBAction)hideViewContainer;
@end
```

my RealViewController.m file

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIViewController *)pickerView{
 return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIViewController *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if(component==option1)
        return[arrayOption count];
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIViewController *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if(component==option1)
        return[arrayOption objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(IBAction)showViewContainer
{
_viewContainer.layer.hidden=NO;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
_viewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0,767,768,258);
}
-(IBAction)hideViewContainer
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
_viewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0,10000,320,206);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
arrayOption=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrayOption addObject:@"qwerty1"];
[arrayOption addObject:@"qwerty2"];
[arrayOption addObject:@"qwerty3"];
[arrayOption addObject:@"qwerty4"];
}
```

Okay, I found my mistake
Instead of #define option1 2 there have to be option1 0. That's it.

Comment: Did you Nslog the array when pickerView is presented?

Comment: Already found mistake. Thanks)

Comment: Instead of #define option1 2 there have to be option1 0. That's it.